# Не смог придумать логику, которая в случае удачной отправки, - выдаст сообщение "Данные успешно отправлены"

Tags: javascript, dom

Есть два поля ввода.
Валидацию придумал, тут все ок.
Но есть трудность в создании логики, чтоб случае успешной отправки данных из input' ов - выводился alert ('данные успешно отправлены').

Перепробовал варианты, которые тут уже для экономии места не показываю (т.к. они не сработали от слова совсем).

Прошу подсказку (может еще один addEventListener в какой-либо цикл вставить или еще что)

```js
'use strict';

let formEl = document.querySelector('form');


let input_1 = document.querySelector('input#first');
let input_2 = document.querySelector('input#second');

let not = document.querySelector('.not')

formEl.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if (formEl[i].value === "") {
      formEl[i].style.background = 'red';
      not.style.display = 'block'
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
})
```

```css
input {
  border-style: solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="first" type="text">
  <input id="second" type="text">
  <button>Отправить</button>
  <div class="not" style="display: none;">Поле не заполнено</div><br>

</form>
```

Comment: Ну так тут нет отправки данных. Это важно! Статус не отследить в вашем случае. Отправка не идет на сервер, у вас всегда будет успешно, даже если вы будете ловить исключения, их не будет.

Answer (score 0):

```
formEl.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if (formEl[i].value === "") {
      formEl[i].style.background = 'red';
      not.style.display = 'block';
      e.preventDefault();
      return;
    }
  }
  alert("Success!");
});
```